# How to dynamically hide fields in a DetailsView (fields count is always 0)

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I am using a `DetailsView` to show the details of a single row from a `DataTable`.

I do *not* know the column names at design time, so I have `AutoGenerateRows = true` in the markup.

```
DataView dv = myDataTable.AsDataView();
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("ResourceID = {0}", resourceId);

dvScoresBreakdown.DataSource = dv;
dvScoresBreakdown.DataBind();
```

There are about 4 columns in the `DataView` which I don't want the `DetailsView` to display - mainly ID columns.

I understand that I should access the `Fields` property of the `DataView` and set the relevant fields invisible:

```
dvScoresBreakdown.Fields[0].Visible = false;
dvScoresBreakdown.Fields[1].Visible = false;
```

However, the `.Fields.Count` is always zero. So I get an index out of bounds exception.

When I say "always zero", I mean it's zero right after the `.DataBind()`, and also in the `OnDataBinding`, `OnDataBound`, and `OnPreRender` events.

But, the DetailsView does render on the page and show everything - all the columns in the original `DataView` - so the dataview is binding!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found out, the way to do it is to remove rows right after the `.DataBind()` method.

```
dvScoresBreakdown.DataSource = dv;
dvScoresBreakdown.DataBind();

dvScoresBreakdown.Rows[0].Visible = false;
dvScoresBreakdown.Rows[1].Visible = false;
```

Hope this can help someone else!

Answer (score -1):

The Columns collection only stores the explicitly declared columns, so if you’re using autogenerated columns, the count will be zero.
If you’re using autogenerated column, after databind you could loop through the rows collection and make the appropriate cells invisible, like:

If dvScoresBreakdown is GridView

```
 dvScoresBreakdown .DataBind();
if (dvScoresBreakdown .Columns.Count > 0)
    dvScoresBreakdown .Columns[0].Visible = false;
else
{
    dvScoresBreakdown .HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in dvScoresBreakdown .Rows)
    {
        gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Like I said, it is a `DetailsView` control and not a `GridView`. There is no such property as `.Columns` on a `DetailsView`. Having said that, you did put me onto the right track of looking at the rows collection - so thanks for that!